# PHP: how to divide STRING by commas?

Tags: php, explode

if I have the STRING:

```
$_GET['string'] = 'array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "My friend Pol, Lucas and Pil", \'HTML without JS, CSS, PHP, JSP or others languages is ...\', 1, 2, 3)';
```

how I can divide this string in yours "LOGICS" values:

```
1
2
3
4
5
"My friend Pol, Lucas and Pil"
'HTML without JS, CSS, PHP, JSP or others languages is ...'
1
2
3
```

this FAIL:

```
preg_split('/\'.*\'|".*"/', $STRING,  PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

and logically

```
explode(',', $_GET['string'])
```

also

but more: what if the STRING represent a ARRAY multidimentional ?

Comment: Why would `$_GET['string']` ever contain a php array? Is there a specific reason you are not using a JSON array like $_GET['string'] = '[1,2,3]'?

Comment: Thanks @MaartenDev the value come from READ FILES of CONFIG: (config.php)

Comment: so why not use an include/require then?

Answer (score 0):

thanks team,
here my solution:

```
$A = ARRAY();
$ARRAY = array_filter(preg_split('/(\'.*?\')|(".*?")/', $STRING, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
foreach($ARRAY AS $i)if(preg_match('/^\'|^"/', $i))array_push($A, $i);
else {
    $i = explode(',', $i);
    foreach($i AS $ii)array_push($A, $ii);
    }
$A = array_filter(array_map('trim', $A));
print_r($A);
```

any improve please?

regards

Comment: oh... this "solution" fail with this string: `"enum('Cocos (Keeling) Islands','Colombia','Congo','Congo, the Democratic Republic of the','Cook Islands','Cote d''Ivoire','Croatia (Hrvatska)','Cuba','Cyprus','Czech Republic')";` (taked from field ENUM of MySQL). Some solution?

Comment: into the file `phpMyAdmin-5.1.0-all-languages\libraries\classes\InsertEdit.php` you find the function **getColumnEnumValues()**, the comment to this function say: "`* @return array column values as an associative array`"... check that!